# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager after Spring Boot migration 2.X to 3.X

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, migration, spring-framework-beans

I'm trying to migrate my spring boot project from 2.X to 3.2.0 and after making all the required syntax / library changes I'm getting a runtime exception found below.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers]: Factory method 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' threw exception with message: Type org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331)
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers]: Factory method 'platformTransactionManagerCustomizers' threw exception with message: Type org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1211)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:517)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:465)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.isAssignableFrom(ResolvableType.java:368)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.isAssignableFrom(ResolvableType.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.checkGenericTypeMatch(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:842)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1650)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1468)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2190)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration.platformTransactionManagerCustomizers(TransactionManagerCustomizationAutoConfiguration.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.ConfigurableTransactionManager
```

Some points to note:

- I'm not using @Transactional annotation anywhere in the project
- I have the spring-boot-starter-web dependency which contains the spring-boot-autoconfigure library and spring-framework which contains this class.
- I've checked whether or not I need to define an implementation of `ConfigurableTransactionManager` and there's nothing on the migration guides about this.

My POM Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-netty</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Misc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.70</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TEST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I thought initially it was something related to having old `javax.inject.Inject` annotations in some beans but after replacing them with the `jakarta.inject.Inject` annotations and also removing them entirely and using Spring's @Autowire I still get the same outcome.

I'm running out of ideas... is this a red herring for something else entirely?

Comment: You can  run `mvn dependency:tree` and see if there are some transient dependency that use `javax` apis then you have to upgrade that dependencies I guess it will help you.

Comment: `ConfigurableTransactionManager` is a new class introduced in Spring Framework 6.1. I would guess that you have `spring-tx` `6.0.x` on the classpath. That module, and all other Spring Framework modules, need to be `6.1.x`. This problem could be avoided entirely if you used Spring Boot's dependency management.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks a lot, strangely `spring-tx` was only found in one dependency `camel-spring-boot` using `6.0.x` with no conflicts.  I'm guessing something must have been moved from `spring-boot-starter-web` because this was working fine previously.  Adding `spring-tx` dependency at `6.1.x` fixed the issue.  Could you clarify Spring Boot's dependency management? I can see a Gradle Plugin (I'm using Maven) and a `spring-boot-dependencies` dependency I can import?  I also have a parent POM with `dependencyManagement` section but a lot of these dependencies are only being used in one module.

Comment: If you're using Maven you have two options: use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your project's parent or import `spring-boot-dependencies` in your `<dependencyManagement>`. It sounds like the latter is the best option for you. You could do that in your existing parent pom if you want to share it among multiple modules.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks a lot, this has been resolved now. I've had to use `spring-boot-dependencies` as I'm required to use a different parent file. However this has also increased the build time quite significantly now... `mvn clean install` from a fresh state now takes over an hour as it's checking a lot more third party libraries for updates.  Running with `mvn clean install -o` for offline resolves the issue but it's not ideal.  Is this to be expected? or should I have excluded something here?  Do you face the same issue in your projects?

Comment: `spring-boot-dependencies` just manages versions and they're all fixed (not snapshots) so it shouldn't affect the number of versions that need to be checked for updates as far as I know. Perhaps you have the Versions plugin bound and it's running its `versions:dependency-updates-report` goal? If so, it has an option not to process `<dependencyManagement>` that you may want to enable.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks Andy, not using the maven versions plugin but I think it's an issue with the Jenkins configuration on our pipeline which is force-updating during each build which checks each dependency.  Will investigate more, thanks so much!